# Mashape multipart-form POST request

Tags: rest, post, curl, multipartform-data, mashape

I have a POST method in my API which uses multipart encoded form data. I have set up the correct header and data settings so that the mashape web interface generated the following curl:

```
curl -X POST --include 'https://sslavov-text-analytics-v1.p.mashape.com/news' \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic ***********' \
  -H 'X-Mashape-Key: ************' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F 'file=@sample.docx' \
  -F 'meta={"documentType": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"};type=application/json'
```

Basically i'm trying to upload a file with a simple paragraph of text for processing. The curious part is that when I run this exact curl in a bash script, everything works smoothly, but when I try to run it through mashape, it says either `400 Bad Request` or `500 Internal Server Error`

In my particular case, these errors are generated when I don't pass correct form or headers. So my question is: Is there an error in the curl syntax or should I keep looking for the error on server side?

EDIT: I figured out what the problem was. `-F 'file=@sample.docx'` was passed before `-F 'meta....'` and that was causing the `500 Internal Server Error` So now the question is: Is there any way to specifically arrange the order of the form fields (because mashape rearranges them aplhabetically)?

Comment: I am willing to provide additional screenshots, should that be necessary

Comment: can you link to API page on Mashape?

Comment: I can't, I haven't published it yet. I can't publish it when something is not working properly which is why I want to know whether to look for the error on my side or to contact mashape support